# Energy density proportional to the cube of the frequencies

Tags: quantum-field-theory

A few years ago I came across a QFT formula that showed, I think, that the energy density was proportional to the cube of the frequency, or the integral over all frequencies where the integrand included the frequency cubed.  I can't remember the formula.  Does anyone know a formula like that?  Thanks.

Comment: Planck's Law? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I didn't realize the fifth power of the wavelength shows up as the third power of the wavenumber.  Thanks.  Why does it change from $\lambda^{-5}$ to $f^3$ when converting between $B(\lambda)$ and $B(f)$?

Comment: Intuitively, it's because the wavelength and the frequency versions of the formula cover the intensity curve in opposite directions, and the intensity curve is not symmetric - the low-frequency side has a very different slope than the low-wavelength (/high-frequency) side.

Comment: @probably_someone Do you know a source that discusses this?

Comment: That’s just basic derivatives. Please try to obtain the relation on your own — all you need to use is $\lambda \sim f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found this in reference to finding out if frequency cubed had any significance in physics. I used `E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2` and `E=pc` for a massless energy.

```
t = (λ/f)/c # λ =c/f=c at 1hz
r = (c/2)/t
V = (4/3)πr^3
V' = 4πr^2
V'' = (8πr)/(2(π)^(2^-1))**2=(8πr)/(4π) # Diameter of 1 cycle per 4π for particle rotation
velocity = v''/t
d = f/V
p = (V*d)*velocity
pc = (p)*c
pc = f^3*c^2
```

Its a lot of noise that just re-defines an existing thing from special relativity, but by removing "momentum" from it, mass is never a factor.

So its not an Energy Density. Its an Energy Intensity

`f^3` is the volume of the wave function. `Intensity=A/V` where `A=Amplitude` of the wave and `V=Volume of 1 cycle of a frequency` and the `radius = (wavelength/2) =(2f)^-1` still. Same as used in the proof above we use V'' since its the diameter

`Intensity=A/(2f^3)^-1 = 2Af^3`

Since the Amplitude is the radius at the peak of the wave, this is a lateral radius where wavelength is longitudinal unit of distance. So If we know a phase angle we can derive the lateral radius, Amplitude.

That's what I used to find the number, `f^3`, that got me to this

Comment: The Planck law is what I was looking for.